# Separa string em camelCase

Tags: javascript

É possível utilizando Javascript converter string em camelCase, ex: `areaEspacoReservado` em `Área espaço reservado` obs: adicionar os acentos onde for necessário ?

Comment: "_Adicionar os acentos onde for necessário_" Aí você forçou um pouco, né

Comment: Sim é possível, desde que você crie um dicionário com todas as palavras acentuadas para fazer a substituição..

Comment: Quais os critérios? Liste todos eles.

Comment: formaDaForma - é "fôrma dá forma" ou "forma da fôrma"? Em alguns casos o acento vai ser impossível de se determinar.

Comment: Também tem que garantir que não haverá palavras que são escritas da mesma maneira mas só se diferenciam pelo acento (como "sabia", "sábia" e "sabiá"). Pode ser que no seu caso não tenha, mas enfim. A variação de strings é tão grande a ponto de você precisar de uma solução tão geral? Talvez seja mais fácil mapear a string inteira (`areaEspacoReservado`) para o seu respectivo texto...

Comment: Os critérios seriam utilizar valores em camelCase que vem nas chaves de um json de forma dinâmica, eu consigo manipular este JSON se eu conseguir adicionar os acentos teria algum problema? ajudaria ?

Comment: @wDrik Creio que os acentos não sejam problema.

Comment: Na minha opinião, colocar os acentos corretamente torna a questão muito ampla, e passível de ser fechada por esse motivo. Para ser feito de forma correta se calhar é coisa para tese de mestrado.

Comment: Na verdade nem precisa do dicionário, basta um algoritimo para as regras gramaticais, ex: área é proparoxitona, logo vai acento...

Comment: @MagicHat e como exatamente o algoritimo vai saber qual a silaba tônica de cada palavra pra poder definir o que é oxitona, paroxitona ou proparoxitona?

Comment: @MáttheusSpoo procure por `algorítimo prosódico`.

Answer (score 1):

É possível, porém trabalhoso. Precisaria criar um "dicionário" de acentuação para fazer a conversão (`area` para `área`, por exemplo). O fluxo seria:

1. Fazer um split das palavras com uma `regex`
2. Efetuar a tradução das palavras com o dicionário
3. Manipular o texto para manter apenas a primeira letra maiúscula

Comment: E mesmo assim não resolveria todos os problemas, pq nessas frases: "Hoje fui na secretaria" e "Hoje conversei com a secretária" o que vai delimitar que `secretaria` deve ou não levar acento?

Comment: Correto, seria necessária uma análise contextual também nesse caso.